# How to fix 4 columns with small images to adjust and fill the spaces in responsive UI?

Tags: css, wordpress, multiple-columns

I'm using wordpress on this site

If you try to resize your browser bit by bit, it has some big spaces that can be filled by the next image. I tried editing the width, but it doesn't work. Any other ideas how to fix it?

Here's a quick image of my problem:
[image]

Comment: Spacing is not related to div padding, its with a inline style width which comes from jquery plugin of your website

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the padding for each div that the images are in. Currently, it's set to 15px. If you set it to a percentage, it would become more responsive.

Alternatively, you could (if you're not already), use media-queries to eliminate the padding under a certain viewport. Something like this:

```
        @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
         div .insert-class-here {padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Hi Rufus, thanks for the reply. I tried to remove the padding and even set it to 1, but the behavior is just the same.

Comment: It's a little hard to help you since you didn't actually post your code, but it looks like the problem might be that all of those divs are positioned absolutely. If I were you, I would look into using a responsive grid, something like this: http://csswizardry.com/csswizardry-grids/